# nginx stream proxy vs http proxy for ssl termination

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running an HTTP service and want to put `nginx` in front for SSL termination. This can be done in two ways; either as a `stream` proxy

```
stream {
    server {
        listen               443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate      /certs/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /certs/privkey.pem;
        proxy_pass           ip-for-backend-service:80;
    }
}
```

or as an `http` proxy

```
http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate      /certs/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /certs/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://ip-for-backend-service:80;
            proxy_set_header ...;
        }
    }
}
```

From a quick glance it seems like that the configuration of the `stream` proxy is *much* simpler since you don't have to add a bunch of extra headers (`proxy_set_header` etc) and other configuration.

I am trying to understand the pros and cons between these two methods, and in particular I have the following questions:

1. Will either method leak more information about the backend service? For example, will the `ip-for-backend-service` be visible?
2. Will either method result in better protection from attacks? I guess if the backend service has flaws it will be visible/exploitable through both options?
3. Which option is more efficient? I *think* that the `stream` option might be faster since it just routes the traffic and there is no http-server in the middle?

Comment: stream will not terminate ssl, so actually these is no choice

Comment: That is not true, you can terminate ssl with the stream config, see e.g. https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/#tlsTerminate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39421271/5087136 etc.

Comment: Oh, somehow missed that part

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With both methods the upstream IP address will remain hidden.

As for the rest:

- `stream` is certainly faster, since less code is executed. However both are well-written C code and when you compare it with network delays, the difference might not be noticeable.
- With `stream` the upstream logs will only contain one client IP address (the address of the proxy server). This can be changed with the [proxy_bind](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind) directive, but requires additional networking setup. On the other hand adding an `X-Forwarded-For` header in the `http` setup is straightforward:

  ```
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  ```
- With `stream` the upstream server needs to be manually configured to consider the incoming connection secure: e.g. Tomcat requires the addition of `scheme="https"` and `secure="true"` on the `<Connector>` element. Using the `http` proxy and a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header the upstream server can decide whether `HTTP` or `HTTPS` was used on a per-connection basis.

The question of the security of the setup is quite opinion-based:

- Using the `http` proxy, you can limit the URI paths that will be proxied, hence you will not expose to the public the administrative part of your website,
- On the other hand, by adding additional computational strain on your system (against the alternative of accessing the upstream server directly), you are more exposed to DDoS attacks.